# Calculating a distance matrix by dtw

Tags: r, dtw

I have two matrices of normalized read counts for control and treatment in a time series day1 to day26. I want to calculate distance matrix by Dynamic Time Wrapping afterward use that for clustering but seems too complicated. I did so; who can help for more clarification please? Thanks a lot

```
> head(control[,1:4])
               MAST2     WWC2  PHYHIPL   R3HDM2
Control_D1  6.591024 5.695156 3.388652 5.756384
Control_D1 8.043454 5.365221 6.859768 6.936970
Control_D3 7.731590 4.868267 6.919972 6.931073
Control_D4 8.129948 5.105528 6.627016 7.090268
Control_D5 7.690863 4.729501 6.824746 6.904610
Control_D6 8.101723 5.334501 6.868990 7.115883
> 

> head(lead[,1:4])
              MAST2     WWC2  PHYHIPL   R3HDM2
Lead30_D1  6.418423 5.610699 3.734425 5.778046
Lead30_D2 7.918360 4.295191 6.559294 6.780952
Lead30_D3 7.807142 4.294722 6.599187 6.716040
Lead30_D4 7.856720 4.432136 6.572337 6.848483
Lead30_D5 7.827311 4.204738 6.607107 6.784094
Lead30_D6 7.848760 4.458451 6.581216 6.943003
>
> dim(control)
[1]   26 2603
> dim(lead)
[1]   26 2603
library(dtw)

for (i in control) { 
  for (j in lead) { 
    result[i,j] <- dtw( dist(control[,,i],lead[,,j]), distance.only=T )$normalizedDistance 
  }
}
```

Says that

```
Error in lead[, , j] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 7):

There have already been questions similar to yours,
but the answers haven't been too detailed.
Here's a breakdown of what you need to know,
in the specific case of R.

## Calculating cross-distance matrices

The [`proxy`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=proxy) package is made specifically for the calculation of cross-distance matrices.
You should check its vignette to know which measures are already implemented by it.
An example of its use:

```
set.seed(1L)
sample_data <- matrix(rnorm(50L), nrow = 5L, ncol = 10L)

suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(proxy))
distance_matrix <- proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "euclidean", 
                               upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
print(distance_matrix)
#>          1        2        3        4        5
#> 1 0.000000 2.636027 3.834764 5.943374 3.704322
#> 2 2.636027 0.000000 2.587398 4.515470 2.310364
#> 3 3.834764 2.587398 0.000000 4.008678 3.899561
#> 4 5.943374 4.515470 4.008678 0.000000 5.059321
#> 5 3.704322 2.310364 3.899561 5.059321 0.000000
```

*Note*: in the context of time series,
`proxy` treats each **row** in a matrix as a series,
which can be confirmed by the fact that `sample_data` above is a `5x10` matrix and the resulting cross-distance matrix is `5x5`.

## Using the DTW distance

The [`dtw`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dtw) package implements many variations of DTW,
and it also leverages `proxy`.
You could calculate a DTW distance matrix with:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dtw))
dtw_distmat <- proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "dtw", 
                           upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
print(dtw_distmat)
#>           1         2         3         4         5
#> 1  0.000000  8.093244 10.151543 13.578930 10.580956
#> 2  8.093244  0.000000  7.261698  9.732505  7.225443
#> 3 10.151543  7.261698  0.000000 11.357395  6.606688
#> 4 13.578930  9.732505 11.357395  0.000000 10.156224
#> 5 10.580956  7.225443  6.606688 10.156224  0.000000
```

## Using custom distances

One nice thing about `proxy` is that it gives you the option to register custom functions.
You seem to be interested in the normalized version of DTW,
so you could do something like this:

```
ndtw <- function(x, y = NULL, ...) {
    dtw::dtw(x, y, ..., distance.only = TRUE)$normalizedDistance
}

pr_DB$set_entry(
  FUN = ndtw,
  names = "ndtw",
  loop = TRUE,
  distance = TRUE
)

ndtw_distmat <- proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "ndtw",
                            upper = TRUE, diag = TRUE)
print(ndtw_distmat)
#>           1         2         3         4         5
#> 1 0.0000000 0.4046622 0.5075772 0.6789465 0.5290478
#> 2 0.4046622 0.0000000 0.3630849 0.4866252 0.3612722
#> 3 0.5075772 0.3630849 0.0000000 0.5678698 0.3303344
#> 4 0.6789465 0.4866252 0.5678698 0.0000000 0.5078112
#> 5 0.5290478 0.3612722 0.3303344 0.5078112 0.0000000
```

See the documentation of `pr_DB` for more information.

## Other DTW implementations

The [`dtwclust`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=dtwclust) package
(which I made)
implements a basic but faster version of DTW which can use multi-threading and also leverages `proxy`:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dtwclust))
dtw_basic_distmat <- proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "dtw_basic", normalize = TRUE)
print(dtw_basic_distmat)
#>      [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]     
#> [1,] 0.0000000 0.4046622 0.5075772 0.6789465 0.5290478
#> [2,] 0.4046622 0.0000000 0.3630849 0.4866252 0.3612722
#> [3,] 0.5075772 0.3630849 0.0000000 0.5678698 0.3303344
#> [4,] 0.6789465 0.4866252 0.5678698 0.0000000 0.5078112
#> [5,] 0.5290478 0.3612722 0.3303344 0.5078112 0.0000000
```

The `dtw_basic` implementation only supports two step patterns and one window type,
but it is considerably faster:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(microbenchmark))
microbenchmark(
  proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "dtw", window.type = "sakoechiba", window.size = 5L),
  proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "dtw_basic", window.size = 5L)
)

Unit: microseconds
                                                                                        expr      min       lq     mean
 proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "dtw", window.type = "sakoechiba",      window.size = 5L) 5279.124 5621.742 6070.069
                            proxy::dist(sample_data, method = "dtw_basic", window.size = 5L)  657.966  710.418  776.474
   median       uq       max neval cld
 5802.354 6348.199 10411.000   100   b
  752.282  814.037  1161.626   100  a
```

Another multi-threaded implementation is included in the [`parallelDist`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=parallelDist) package,
although I haven't personally tested it.

## Multivariate or multi-dimensional time series

A single multivariate series is commonly a matrix where time spans the rows and the multiple variables span the columns.
DTW also works for them:

```
mv_series1 <- matrix(rnorm(15L), nrow = 5L, ncol = 3L)
mv_series2 <- matrix(rnorm(15L), nrow = 5L, ncol = 3L)
print(dtw_distance <- dtw_basic(mv_series1, mv_series2))
#> [1] 22.80421
```

The nice thing about `proxy` is that it can calculate distances between objects contained in lists too,
so you can put several multivariate series in lists of matrices:

```
mv_series <- lapply(1L:5L, function(dummy) {
  matrix(rnorm(15L), nrow = 5L, ncol = 3L)
})

mv_distmat_dtwclust <- proxy::dist(mv_series, method = "dtw_basic")
print(mv_distmat_dtwclust)
#>      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]    
#> [1,]  0.00000 27.43599 32.14207 36.42211 31.19279
#> [2,] 27.43599  0.00000 20.88470 23.88436 29.73219
#> [3,] 32.14207 20.88470  0.00000 22.14376 29.99899
#> [4,] 36.42211 23.88436 22.14376  0.00000 28.81111
#> [5,] 31.19279 29.73219 29.99899 28.81111  0.00000
```

## Your case

Regardless of what you choose,
you can probably use `proxy` to get your result,
but since you haven't provided your whole data,
I can't give you a more specific example.
I presume that `dtwclust::dtw_basic(control[, 1:4], lead[, 1:4], normalize = TRUE)` would give you the distance between one pair of series,
assuming you're treating each one as a multivariate series with 4 variables.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is "why am I getting this error?" the answer is that you're trying to subset a matrix, which is a two dimensional array, according to a 3rd dimension.

see:

```
dim(lead)
# [1] 26 2603
lead[,,6.418423] # yes, that's the value j has the first time through the loop
# This will reproduce your error
lead[,,1]
# This will also reproduce your error
```

Hopefully you can see now that you have a few problems:

1. You're trying to subset a matrix according to a 3rd dimension
2. Your `i` and `j` values are the values in `control` and `lead` respectively. You can use them as their values, or you can generate the index, e.g., `for(i in seq_along(control)` if you're planning to use it for something other than getting that same value out.
3. Taking it to the next step, it's unclear what you want to pass to the `dist` function. `dist` takes a single matrix and computes the distance between its rows. You seem to be trying to pass it two values from two different matrices, or perhaps two subsets of two different matrices. It looks like you might need to go back and look at the examples in the documentation for `xtr`

Comment: Thank you, I want to compute a distance matrix by by Dynamic Time Wrapping by dtw R package. I have a control matrix and a lead treated samples. Help me please

Comment: @Fereshteh did you understand the first two problems I listed?

Comment: Sorry, I am an agricultural graduate, too new in R.

Comment: I don't mean to sound harsh, but if you can't understand the first two problems in the list of 3 problems, then you need to work on the basic concepts in R first before stack overflow can help you resolve problems with your code. You could try: https://www.datacamp.com/courses/free-introduction-to-r

Comment: Sorry I could not figure out how calculate distance matrix, I am an agricultural graduate, too new in R. I have 26 cell lines under lead (pb) treatment from day 1 to day 26 with 26 control. I want to calculate distance matrix by dtw R package and use distance matrix for rTensor package to compare a network of control and treatment.