# How to customise what is returned by proxy::dist with dtw distance function

Tags: r, proxy, distance, similarity, dtw

I've got a list of time series:

```
ex <- list(ts1 = structure(c(15.33, 46.83, 69.93, 79.59, 85.785, 78.132, 
61.812, 189.108, 188.904, 159.936, 35.175, 62.37, 77.49, 85.785, 
87.36, 17.952, 198.696, 198.084, 159.936, 157.692), .Dim = 5:4, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")), .Tsp = c(1, 5, 
1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix")), ts2 = structure(c(34.65, 
43.47, 34.125, 62.424, 10.2, 45.084, 43.575, 34.125, 27.72, 10.812, 
48.756, 92.616), .Dim = 3:4, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("var1", 
"var2", "var3", "var4")), .Tsp = c(1, 3, 1), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix")), ts3 = structure(c(33.915, 59.325, 47.736, 8.772, 
54.18, 80.115, 4.08, 61.2), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")), .Tsp = c(1, 2, 
1), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix")))
```

I would like to calculate the dtw distances between each pair in the list. As reading in `dtw` package register `dtw` distance as a distance function in the database of `proxy` distances `pr_DB`, I can just use `proxy::dist` to quickly calculate all the distances. The problem is that `proxy::dist` seems to return raw distances, while as my time series are of different length I need it to return normalised distance. `dtw::dtw` function returns a list with `normalizedDistance` as one element. So how can I change what is return by `proxy::dist` and make it return `normalizedDistance`? Or maybe is there another way to calculate each pair normalised distances? (Of course, as my dataset is large I need to avoid looping over all pairs).

Here's a short code to help to see an issue:

```
> proxy::dist(ex, method = 'dtw')
         ts1      ts2
ts2 822.2551         
ts3 909.3705 195.2110
> dtw::dtw(ex[[1]], ex[[2]])$distance
[1] 822.2551
> dtw::dtw(ex[[1]], ex[[2]])$normalizedDistance
[1] 102.7819
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50776685/5793905).

Answer (score 0):

If we are looking for pairwise, then try with `combn`

```
library(dtw)
combn(ex, 2, FUN = function(x) dtw(x[[1]], x[[2]])$normalizedDistance)
#[1] 102.78188 129.91007  39.04219
```

Checking by individually applying the `dtw` function on the pairs

```
dtw::dtw(ex[[2]], ex[[3]])$normalizedDistance
#[1] 39.04219
dtw::dtw(ex[[1]], ex[[3]])$normalizedDistance
#[1] 129.9101
```